# Polling consumer thread stopping automatically

Tags: apache-camel

I am having a scenario where I am using consumer template to receive file from a endpoint. The Endpoint could be either File System or FTP site. Currently I am using only File System with following endpoint URL:

`file://D:/metamodel/Seach.json?noop=true&idempotent=false`

On every hit to following code:

```
Exchange exchange = consumerTemplate.receive(endPointURI, timeout);

if (exchange != null) {
    String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    consumerTemplate.doneUoW(exchange);
    return body;
}
```

It creating a new Camel context thread and after some hits it giving error as

`java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: PollingConsumer on Endpoint[file://D:/metamodel/Seach.json?noop=true&idempotent=false] is not started, but in state:Stopped`

I am not sure why this is happening and its sporadic in nature.
Any suggestion on this would do great help.

Comment: I guess problem is related to concurrent number of threads, which are being created somewhere else, not mentioned above. For example, it could have been a seda component and whenever consumer size breaks the limit, it is showing this error. Though, not sure why that should happen. Could be something to do with Camel as well. A relevant article on RejectedExecutionException (http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/rejectedexecutionexception/java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionexception-how-to-solve-rejectedexecutionexception/) could be helpful to understand the problem.